# Can Kosh see the future?

Tags: babylon-5

Visions of the future are a thing in Babylon 5.  Centauri in particular seem to have some prophetic things going on, and Technomages may as well.

Kosh tells Sheridan "If you go to Z'ha'dum you will die." This later turns out to be so. Was Kosh actually prophesizing? Or was he just commenting on how dangerous the place was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not any more so than other characters.**

Kosh tells Sheridan that early on, when Sheridan is just learning the truth about the Shadows.  Later on, when Sheridan leans on Kosh to bring the Vorlon off the bench and into the war, Kosh tells him that he won't be able to support him on Z'ha'dum.  Sheridan repeats his earlier "If you go to Z'ha'dum, you will die." back to him, and Kosh emphasizes, "Yes. Now."

This isn't prophecy, these are warnings.  The homeworld of the Shadows is an incredibly dangerous place.  Kosh telling him this is informing Sheridan that it's a suicide mission.  Kosh being able to protect Sheridan made it slightly less of one.  So, not likely to be prophecy.

The most prophetic things Kosh puts out are the visions he gives to Sheridan.  So it's still possible.  Those visions, however, could also simply be explained as metaphors, about things Kosh already knows for fact, rather than any sight on the future.

Comment: "Prophecy is a guess that comes true. When it doesn't, it's a metaphor."

Answer (score 0):

Due to time travel of Sinclair, Kosh knew the future till the moment of time travel.
But, as for Z'ha'dum, Kosh was preventing Sheridan from talking to the Shadows, he didn't wanted to give the Shadows a chance to convert Sheridan to their side.

Comment: Is there evidence to suggest that Kosh thought Sheridan might turn?

Comment: On one hand, in "2x21 - Comes The Inquisitor" Vorlons were concerned about his loyality. But! in "3x15 - Interludes And Examinations" Kosh says "I will not be there to help you when you go to Z'ha'dum", so it was OK to let him go alone, they didn't want to prevent it...

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten about Jack. Perhaps you could add that information to your answer.

Comment: @Nishi - *Comes the Inquisitor* was not about loyalty to the Vorlon.  If it was, the conclusion of that interrigation - essentially, Delenn and Sheridan being loyal to *each other* over the Vorlon cause - would make no sense.